# Azure Devops Artifacts: disable saving packages from upstream sources

Tags: npm, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I have a feed for npm packages with npmjs set as upstream source (by default). When you try to install your uploaded custom package with other dependencies, those dependency packages get saved automatically in your feed to save time for future installs. I however do not want it and want my feed to only host my own packages and just download from the upstream source every time an install is made. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Not me, but my boss wanted to. I told him the benefits (saving time) but he still does not want to.

Comment: Yeah, my company is being stingy with money and wanted to stay real low on the artifact storage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I did instead is make all our packages in a scope and modify the npmrc file to use the azure feed for only that scope so the rest of the packages still gets downloaded from registry.npmjs.org

here's what the .npmrc file would look like

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/

@customScope:registry=https://ourregistry.org/ourfeed

always-auth=true
```

Comment: So, instead of relying solely on your Azure Artifact Feed to source both custom packages and the ones on NPM registry, have two sources, and put the public ones first so the custom packages are pulled only when needed?

Comment: sorry for the late reply but yes that's how it would work

Comment: To change the scope in company packages (npm init --scope=myco) and then publish it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do this?

The answer is yes.

**If you are creating new feed**, you could uncheck the option Upstream sources when you creating the new feed:

[image]

**If the feed is already created by you**, you could delete the upstream sources. Go to the `Settings`->`Upstream sources`:

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: The thing is, I still want to use registry.npmjs.org as an upstream source, I just don't want azure devops saving and hosting the other packages.

But thanks for giving an answer.