# devops feed shows packages from upstream sources. Can I disable that?

Tags: tfs, devops

I have two devops (on premis) feeds, in separate projects.

I have two nuget packages, one in each feed.  Both packages have a dependency on the Dapper package in the nuget gallery.  One feed does not list the upstream dependencies and lists no upstream feeds, and the other one lists the upstream dependencies and lets me pick nuget, maven, npmjs, and PYPI feed source options when viewing packages.

I don't really want the feed to show upstream dependencies because it clutters everything, and I can't figure out why the two feeds have different behavior.  Is this a config setting somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a feed and then enable the below option **Upstream sources**, you will encounter this issue that those dependency packages get saved automatically in your feed.
[image]

To avoid this now, you could check if this package enables the option **Allow external sourced versions** as this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-behavior?view=azure-devops&tabs=nuget#enable-upstream-behavior) stated.

Also you could delete [the upstream sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/tutorials/protect-oss-packages-with-upstream-sources?view=azure-devops&tabs=npm). Go to the `Settings`->`Upstream sources`:
[image]
See [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59154632/azure-devops-artifacts-disable-saving-packages-from-upstream-sources) for more details.